# What should be done with unused input of an LM339 and LM358?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, comparator

I am designing a circuit using an [LM339](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm339b.pdf) and an [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbt3j/snosbt3j.pdf), and I am not using all of the contained comparators or op-amps. I searched through the datasheets, and they did not explicitly state what should happen with unused inputs/outputs (unless I missed it or used the wrong search terms).

I also looked online on multiple forum pages (this one included); the information is contradictory. Some sites said to ground inputs, while other sites said to ground one of the inputs and pull up the other input.

The information I found on the LM358, or other op-amps, said to ground the inverting input and connect the output to the noninverting input.

So, what should I do with the unused inputs/outputs of these ICs?

Comment: Duplicate/related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/176597/2028, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/41611/2028

Comment: This TI application note, [How to Properly Configure Unused Operational Amplifiers](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa204a/sboa204a.pdf), may be of interest to you as well.